# Is there a way to dynamically instrument text in vega-lite?

Tags: vega-lite

I have a use case where I want to read from the brush values and update a title/string---e.g., create the text, `you selected the states CA, WA, and NY` as a companion to a bar chart where the user has selected CA, WA and NY.

How might this be done?

I'm aware of the [`text` mark](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/layer_text_heatmap.html), as well we [`title`](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/title/). However the former seems to be a tight mapping from the data (not signals), and the latter cannot be dynamic.

Thanks!

Comment: Vega-Lite currently does not support signals. Could you use Vega-Lite to generate a Vega spec and then modify the Vega spec to dynamically change the title with a signal?